# In a chrooted env, ls command shows "?" instead of UTF8 characters

Tags: chroot, locale, unicode

I'm trying to set up a chrooted env for ssh users, but our QA discovers that UT8 characters are replaced by "?":

```
xstorenas>ls /mnt/hires/tsi/
??????????????????
```

But when I do a simple for loop:

```
xstorenas>for f in /mnt/hires/tsi/*; do 
    echo $f; 
done
/mnt/hires/tsi/рэпертуар
```

I have a /etc/locale.conf, and a full /usr/share/locale available and LANG is set correctly:

```
xstorenas>printenv LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Therefore I could not find what is missing in the chrooted env (as it is working as expected outside the chrooted env).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `ls` depends on locales, and locales need a pile of support files to work.  You probably don't have these files in your `chroot` jail.  Example on Linux:

```
$ strace -eopen ls >/dev/null
[...]
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[...]
```

You can copy these files to the `chroot` jail to make `ls` work, but that isn't a great idea since locale files can open you to various security exploits.  You probably shouldn't need to run `ls` in a `chroot`ed environment to begin with.